# log the exception in spring using aspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, logging, exception, aspectj

Please don't hesitate to edit the question or to ask more details about the questin.

I know I can `log` the `ArithmeticException` of the below method using the `aspectJ` as,

```
public void afterThrowingAspect(){
    System.out.println("This is afterThrowingAspect() !");      
    int i=2/0;
    System.out.println("i value : "+i);
}
```

The AspectJ class has,

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.pointel.aop.test1.AopTest.afterThrowingAspect(..))",throwing= "error")
public void logAfterError(JoinPoint joinPoint,Throwable error) {
    System.out.println("Hi jacked Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    log.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    log.info("Error report is : " + error);

}
```

Normally I can handle exception using the `TRY` and `CATCH` block and `log` the errors in the every `CATCH` block as ,

```
public void someMehtod(){
    try{        
        int i=2/0;
        System.out.println("i value : "+i);
    }catch{ArithmeticException err){
        log.info("The exception you got is : " + err);
    }
}
```

But I don't like to do the `logging` like with every single `catch` block individually in all the `java` classes of my project like ,

```
log.info("The exception you got is : " + err);
```

I would like to do the `logging` inside `CATCH` block in my application using the `aspectJ` class.

Hope you are all understand my question.Thanks.

Comment: If you define the @AfterThrowing pointcut as `pointcut = "execution(* com.pointel.*(..))"` you will trigger the @AfterThrowing aspect everytime an exception is raised in the package and sub-packages of com.pointel. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: @Julien I don't need to log the `@AfterThrowing` methods . I need to log the `exception` in the catch block using  `aspectJ` . I this possible ?

Comment: You can not advise the catch-block inside a method. Only entry and exit of a method can be advised, not it's content. If you catch an exception occuring in a method inside that same method, logging the exception with aspectj is only possible if you throw the exception higher up in the call stack from the catch-block (and log it after the method is done - in @AfterThrowing).

Comment: @Sheltem Thanks for quick reply. Can you please provide me a small example.This would help me to understand and implement in my code easily.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to simply remove the try/catch from your code and simply log the exception in your aspect.

```
public void someMehtod(){
        int i=2/0;
        System.out.println("i value : "+i);
}
```

Because you don't re-throw the exception in the aspect then it won't bubble up. Although this is possible I strongly advise you to think more about what you are trying to do here. Why do you need to log the fact that an exception has been thrown? Exceptions aren't necessarily only for errors but can occur in normal code journeys. Simply logging only the exception name is unlikely to help you debug the problem.  Therefore, you will probably want a bespoke log message for each catch block. If you do find repetition you could create a method to log out the result.

Hope this helps,

Mark